# EC2 Instance Error: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available(server sent:public key)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have recently started an EC2 instance of Ubuntu 14.04 and installed Glastopf honeypot on it with ssh connection using Putty. Before starting the honeypot in background, I was able to login to the instance using putty ( I have done all the prerequisites such puttygen for .ppk private key) but after starting Glastopf, I am getting the above error for the same settings.

Moreover, I have read another question and tried all ways such as changing the user name, defining the path of .ppk key again, creating a new key pair from the console of AWS and restarting the instance.

Please suggest me a way-out as my honeypot is working fine at public dns but I am not able to login to instance.